# splitting the outerHTML attribute in python

Tags: python, selenium, attributes, split

I would want to split out particular text from the outerHTML attribute for a web link.

```
while Id is true:
    link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='bu:ms:all-sp:2']")
    href = link.get_attribute("outerHTML")  
    link.click()
    # This will load the link in the same page !
    self.assertIn(href, self.page.get_current_url())
```

When I print the href, output would be,

```
<a id="bu:ms:all-sp:8" href="/euro/tennis" class="Pointer"><span class="SportImg8"></span> Tennis <span class="NumEvt">51</span></a>
```

I would want to split this and assert the value of href alone (/euro/tennis) with the current URL.

Could anyone please help me out here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get `href` attribute instead of `outerHTML`:

```
href = link.get_attribute("href")
```